# Change values according to the routeProvider

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
 var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);

mainApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.tab = 3;

});



mainApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/cc', {
            templateUrl: 'cc.html',
        })
        .when('/pl', {
            templateUrl: 'pl.html',
        })
```

I am using route to show different pages depending on user selection. I am using `ng-class` to change the appearance of the selected page link once the user clicks on that link.
`ng-class` depends on the value of a variable `tab`, set in controller.

Problem - When I reload the page www.foo.com/pl the view shows the pl.html but the value of `tab` is reset to 3. Thereby making other link as active and not "pl".

I want the value of `tab` to change according to the page being loaded(Even if I refresh the value should change accordingly). How can I attain this?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a param to every route:

```
mainApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/cc', {
        templateUrl: 'cc.html',
        selected: 1 
    })
    .when('/pl', {
        templateUrl: 'pl.html',
        selected: 2
    })
```

Then inject `$route` into controller:

```
mainApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $route) {
    $scope.tab = $route.current.selected;
});
```

And make a verification verify in html with `ng-class` directive:

```
<a href="/cc" ng-class="{active: tab == 1}">link1</li>
<a href="/pl" ng-class="{active: tab == 2}">link2</li>
```

---

**Another way** is to use `$location` service.

```
mainApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.tab = $location.path();
});
```

Html:

```
<a href="/cc" ng-class="{active: tab == '/cc/'}">link1</li>
<a href="/pl" ng-class="{active: tab == '/pl/'}">link2</li>
```

Comment: and also try using different controllers for different html pages/views

Comment: I can see an error in my console when I try this
Error: $route.current is undefined

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid

I had tried that. But it did not work for me I was still facing the same issue. Hope I am able to get you.

Here is the code-

 `var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);

mainApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.tab = 3;
  
});
mainApp.controller('CreditCardController', function($scope) {
            $scope.tab = 1;
         });
 
 
 
mainApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/cc', {
            templateUrl: 'cc.html',
   controller: 'CreditCardController'
        })`

Let me know if you meant the same thing

Comment: Added another way to achieve the result in my post.

Comment: Thanks @LazarevAlexandr

The 2nd way did the trick. Appreciate your help :)